# Does this "ribbon" design fit with SE Community?

Tags: website-design, interface-design

I love SE Community, and I love badges, it has something similar with Xbox achievements. I used to play a game called Gears of War 3, it has a cool system called **Ribbons**. Basically you played this game and you got ribbons for your performance at every single battle. Here are some examples.

[image]

So I was thinking, if we could have a similar system in SE Community, ribbons based on your everyday activities.

I am a new guy into design world, and here are my ribbons design.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I am not here to ask whether this proposal of ribbons is OK or not, this question has been discussed at Meta Stackoverflow. I want to know does this kind of graphic design (whether Gears of War 3 style or my terrible design ) fit with the whole SE Community?

Comment: In that it's a military theme, I'd likely say it'd fit military.se but not likely other sites.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would say no.

- Most of all: They will not look good in tiny versions
- They are too "predefined" in style: SE have a multitude of sites, and
  in very few of them will it fit the rest of the site
- They are too "militant"/gamey with over/undertones of religion, imperialism, war, power etc
- The symbolism will have to be learned on a much more complex level
  than the existing ones.
  They are too complex in shape and form

Mind: They are well made, they are solid designs. But not for SE.